# Java LibGDX drawing multiple shapes each with unique renderers

Tags: java, libgdx, polygon, shapes, shape-rendering

I'm creating a game with LibGDX using JAVA and I've hit a problem I can't solve even after a week's worth of trying. I have shapes being drawn with the ShapeRenderer class, and I have multiple classes and methods interacting with each other. A shape grows on the screen and when the user clicks the screen, the shape stops growing and the second shape begins to grow.

I have an array of ShapeRenderer's and Polygon's and I must draw each shape with a different ShapeRenderer and different Polygon. For example a triangle must be rendered using ShapeRenderer[1] and Polygon[1]. The next triangle on that level must be drawn with ShapeRenderer[2] and Polygon[2]. This is to avoid clashing values and rotations when drawing Polygons on the same ShapeRenderer.

My particular problem is one method I created, "DrawStar" is given a number (starts with 1 representing the first star) and draws that star using ShapeRenderer[1] and Polygon[1]. This means the first star is being drawn then when I click the screen, IDEALLY, the first star should stop growing and the second star should begin to be rendered with ShapeRenderer[2] and Polygon[2].

Here's the problem: Let's say this particular level has been written so that 2 stars are going to grow. The method "DrawStar" will be given the number "1" and draw the first star as it grows, then the method "DrawStar" is given the number "2" and it draws the second star (this isn't visually a problem yet since the star's polygon starts with values of 0 and doesn't increase until the second click so even if it is being drawn it's not visible) and it continues to draw the two stars simultaneously, it basically draws all the stars for that level one after the other i.e. DrawShape(1) then DrawShape(2) then DrawShape(1) then DrawShape(2) etc.

This is my code:

```
public void drawFiveStar(FiveStar star, int num) {
 shapeRenderer[num].begin(ShapeType.Line);
 shapeRenderer[num].setColor(Color.RED);
 poly[num].setVertices(star.verticiesStar);
 poly[num].rotate(1);
 poly[num].setOrigin(star.originX, star.originY);
 shapeRenderer[num].polygon(poly[num].getTransformedVertices());
 shapeRenderer[num].end();
}
```

Star represents the star object passed through and num represents the shape number to draw, as explained in the above example with ShapeRenderer[1] and Polygon[1]. The problem is it will DrawFiveStar(Star1, 1), DrawFiveStar(Star1, 2), DrawFiveStar(Star1, 1),  DrawFiveStar(Star1, 2).... UNTIL I click the mouse button and it moves onto the next star object  DrawFiveStar(Star2, 1),  DrawFiveStar(Star2, 2),  DrawFiveStar(Star2, 1),  DrawFiveStar(Star2, 2)....

The problem with the code above is that the whole point of using a ShapeRenderer array is so that for the second shape, a new, fresh ShapeRenderer is used. This code has it so that the first star object will use both ShapeRenderers and by the time I click to prompt the second star object to grow, both ShapeRenderers have been used to draw the first star object. Ideally it should be only the first ShapeRenderer used to draw the first star object and then when the second object begins to grow that is drawn with the second ShapeRenderer. I tried many solutions none of which produced the desired results of the ideal solution I just described.

It's a programming problem that I can't figure out because the code needs to be dynamic so that if it were 3 or 100 shapes the code would still use a different ShapeRenderer for each star object. Again, this is because drawing multiple shapes on one ShapeRenderer object and rotating them leads to really strange results with shapes flying everywhere, drawing multiple rotating shapes on separate ShapeRenderer objects solves this problem. That is what I'm trying to achieve here.

Read Level > See there are 2 shapes to be drawn > Use 2 shape renderers to draw these 2 shapes

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of unclear what your issue is, but I'm guessing that you are conflating two different ideas into the `num` variable that is passed in, so it's not doing what you want.

Is `num` the shape renderer index you want to use, or is it the shape instance you want to draw? If these are distinct, you need to pass two different int values to your method, and use them appropriately.

That said, if you think you need more than one ShapeRenderer, you must be using it incorrectly. It is a very flexible class and should have no problems with drawing multiple types of shapes in the desired locations. Figure out what you're doing wrong and fix it, so you will only need one. A ShapeRenderer is kind of a heavy object. Each instance has a large backing array, has a mesh stored on the GPU, and loads a ShaderProgram. You definitely do not want to load 100 identical shaders to draw 100 shapes.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll look into making it work with one shape renderer. I had the problem a long time ago rotating 2 shapes with one shape renderer object where it would produce funny results and it was solved by using a different shape renderer for every object. That's not scalable though I guess since it uses a lot of memory to create 100 instances of it

Answer (score 0):

If using a single `ShapeRenderer` creates problems, maybe you are changing the transformation matrix, for example by using translations and rotations? In this case you need to save the original matrix first and restore it after the transformations.

**Example**

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
for(Shape shape: shapes)
{
 Matrix4 tf = shapeRenderer.getTransformMatrix().cpy();
 shapeRenderer.translate([...]);
 shapeRenderer.rotate([...];
 // ... create your shape ...
 shapeRenderer.setTransformMatrix(tf);
}
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Comment: Thanks very much I managed to resolve it with only one shape renderer, the error I had was the polygon i drew with shape renderers did not match the sprite i drew with spritebatch. The problem was as I moved onto further levels, I needed to reset the sprite declaration or it's last position was memorised and didn't match the polygon. Thanks!